# UTF8 php-ajax-jquery issue?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, utf-8

I'm posting some text into my sql INSERT statements and once the text get's into the database it doesn't show as expected.

Example:
This is what I get inside my database: **laÅ¾ljivo**. This is what I should get  **lažljivo** (language:Croatian).

In my ajax-jquery I've put the following:

> contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

In my .php file I've put the following:

> header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

Keep in mind that when I insert the text directly into my db (via workbench or phpmyadmin) then the text is normal hence the problem appears to be when the text is transfered to the .php file. Apart from that, I don't get any error by the system.

Comment: You probably need to run `SET NAMES utf8` before inserting'

Comment: @Mihai that worked, I spent 2 hours figuring what went wrong... You can post the answer if you wish to earn some more points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header contentType is a different thing from mysql connection which also need to be set,you can even set it in your cnf file so it stays utf8

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Comment: to achieve it: $conn->set_charset("utf8");